# Product of multiple lists--individual lists vs array of lists, need help understanding

Tags: python, set, python-2.x, product, python-itertools

Forewarning: I'm new to Python and I'm teaching myself, so this question may just have a trivial solution--any help (and patience) is very much appreciated!

Okay, big picture is that I want to get the union of all possible intersections of a variable number of lists. I'm not really sure how to explain the general-case problem I'm running into, so for the sake of this question, I'll just use an example with 3 lists (but again, the actual number of lists will vary):

Suppose we have the following:

```
>>>from itertools import product

>>>l1=[1,2,3]
>>>l2=[1,4,5]
>>>l3=[1,6,7]
>>>
>>>array=[l1,l2,l3]
>>>
>>>
>>>list(product(array))
[([1, 2, 3],), ([1, 4, 5],), ([1, 6, 7],)]
>>>
>>>list(product(l1,l2,l3)
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 6), (1, 1, 7), (1, 4, 1), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 1), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 6), (2, 1, 7), (2, 4, 1), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 5, 1), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 6), (3, 1, 7), (3, 4, 1), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 7), (3, 5, 1), (3, 5, 6), (3, 5, 7)]
```

My questions are:

1. Why doesn't `list(product(array)) == list(product(l1,l2,l3))`?
2. Using `array`, how can I get the same output as `list(product(l1,l2,l3))`?

For more context:

Ultimately, the goal is to get the union of all possible combinations of the intersections of the lists. I.e.;

```
1>>>for x in product(l1,l2,l3):
...     newArray.append(reduce(set.intersection, [set(e) for e in array])
2>>>u=reduce(set.union, [set(e) for e in newArray])
3>>>u
set([1])
```

Except, because I don't know how many lists I'll have (in my code, they're being appended onto `array` by a loop), I want line `1` to be something like `for x in product(array):`, not `for x in product(l1,l2,l3):`.

Comment: You just want `product(*array)` here. Do you understand the “splat syntax”, pasting an iterable into a function call as a bunch of separate arguments, or do you need a link to an explanation?

Comment: If you're curious why `product(array)` (and even `product()`) is legal despite being useless: First, mathematically, you can write `product_n=1_to_1(n)`. More importantly, it means you can write `product(*rows)` even when `rows` is some value you were passed by a caller that may only have one row, or none, and you can likewise write `product(array, repeat=power)` even if `power` might be only 1 or 0.

Comment: @abarnert: Thank you, `product(*array)` worked! Also, a link to an explanation on 'splat syntax' will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Why doesn't list(product(array))=list(product(l1,l2,l3))?

Well the `itertools.product()` takes in iterables and then produces the Cartesian product amongst them. So when you do list(product(array)) you are basically trying to take cartesian product of a single list(?) and notice the commas in the output of the same signifying cartesian product between one list and empty iterable.

> 2) Using array, how can I get the same output as list(product(l1,l2,l3))?

Notice your problem boils down to being to convert the `arr` list to `*args` while calling the function.We have the `*` operator for this, So for the answer just do:

`product(*arr)`

From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax *expression appears in the function call, expression
>   must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated
>   as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are
>   positional arguments x1, ..., xN, and expression evaluates to a
>   sequence y1, ..., yM, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional
>   arguments x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM.

Since you must mentioned that you are learning on your own,
this is also covered in the python tutorial, in a section titled [Unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll take a look. I really appreciate it.